# faces-redirect working when hard coded into xhtml but not from result of method call

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to make sure the url reflects the current page properly.

When I change page this way:

```
     <h:form>
        <h3>Redirect</h3>
        <h:commandButton type="submit" action = "page1?faces-redirect=true" value = "Page1" />
    </h:form>
```

it works properly updating the page to "webapp/page1.xhtml"

But when I update it through a method call:

```
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton type="submit" action="#{navigationController.showPage}"
                         value="Page1">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{navigationController.pageId}" value="1"/>
        </h:commandButton>

    </h:form>
```

With java code

```
    public String showPage() {
    if (pageId == null) {
        return "home";
    }
    if (pageId.equals("1")) {
        return "page1?faces-redirect = true";
    } else {
        return "home";
    }
```

It won't update properly despite moving to the right page.

Comment: `"page1?faces-redirect=true"` is not the same as `"/page1.xhtml?faces-redirect = true"`

Comment: @BalusC Yeah i forgot to change that. Either way it does not work. It has been updated to reflect the actual code i've got

Comment: `"page1?faces-redirect=true"` is still not the same as `"page1?faces-redirect = true"`

Comment: You make a very good point. Did not realise that would cause an issue